# setOnClickListener not responding when button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to java but in this case, the button is not responding at all when it is clicked, no errors in the logcat are showing up, the ID of the button is correct and no other posts on here helped solve the issue, this is not all the code but hopefully, this will be enough.

```
public class activity_main extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }


    int error_count;

    public void on_click() {
        Button page_2 = findViewById(R.id.page_2);
        page_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {

                    int mother_edu_input = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mother_edu_input)).getText().toString());
                    error_writer("Text_View_Warning_1", mother_edu_input, 4);        

                    if (error_count > 0) {
                        throw new NullPointerException();
                    } else {
                        Intent page_1_button = new Intent(activity_main.this, revision_time.class);
                        startActivity(page_1_button);
                    }

                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You set your listener inside a method called `on_click()` and it doesn't appear like you call this method anywhere.

You should probably call `on_click()` inside your `onCreate()` to set the listener when creating your activity.